# Windows High Contrast Mode: How are colours computed? How can colours be specified for focused elements?

Tags: css, windows, accessibility, high-contrast

How does Windows High Contrast decide which colours it uses to display website elements?

And is it possible to let it display other colours when an element is focused?

For example, on https://www.post.ch/en, the "Consignment number" input field is displayed in another colour when it is focused, but for most other elements the color always stays the same, even when the focus styles define other colours.

Comment: I do not know the precise algorithm, but it uses the luminosity of the colors and the user settings to determine what color to display. The reason that the focus styles are not showing up is that they are too close to the unfocused style and therefore do not trigger the thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

I think that as long as the contrast ratio is above 14:1 they keep the original color. In other case, they use the customized values.

[High-contrast mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848048(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The text colors in the high-contrast themes have been authored to be
>   compliant with the Microsoft Accessibility guidelines. We maintain a
>   14:1 high-contrast ratio between foreground and background. If the
>   colors that are enabled by default are not suitable to a particular
>   end user, they can easily be customized through the control panel
>   settings for ‘Window Color’ in those high-contrast themes.